# Stream Closed IO Error when using CSV Library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to get an array of hashes from parsing a CSV file using `CSV` library.

I currently have this method which works:

```
def rows
  rows = []

  CSV.foreach(@csv_file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    rows << row.to_hash
  end

  rows
end
```

but when I change it to this I get the `stream closed` error.

```
def rows
  CSV.foreach(@csv_file.path, headers: true).map(&:to_hash)
end
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the source code of [`::foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) :

```
def self.foreach(path, options = Hash.new, &block)
  encoding =  options.delete(:encoding)
  mode     =  "rb"
  mode     << ":#{encoding}" if encoding
  open(path, mode, options) do |csv|
    csv.each(&block)
  end
end
```

It internally, opening the file using [`CSV::open`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open), *with a block*. So, once the block is closed, the `IO` object got closed, internally. Now as you are trying to access the closed `IO` object, you are getting the error.

From the doc of `CSV::open`

> This method works like Ruby’s `open()` call, in that it will pass a `CSV` object to a provided block and close it when the block terminates,...

The `IO` object returned by `::foreach` is actually returned by the `CSV::open`, within the method `def self.foreach ...`.

Example :

```
2.1.0 :016 > require 'csv'
 => true 
2.1.0 :017 > CSV.open("Gemfile")
 => <#CSV io_type:File io_path:"Gemfile" encoding:UTF-8 lineno:0 col_sep:"," row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\""> 
2.1.0 :018 > CSV.open("Gemfile") { |c| c }
 => <#CSV io_type:File io_path:"Gemfile" encoding:UTF-8 lineno:0 col_sep:"," row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\""> 
2.1.0 :019 > CSV.open("Gemfile") { |c| c }.read
IOError: closed stream
```

Comment: Thanks Arup, so is there a better way for me to do the above or just what I have already got ?

Comment: @Ollie2619 Your first code is perfect and Ruby like.. I will go with that one.